# Searching Outlook 2010 Meeting Request Events c#

Tags: c#, events, ms-office, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I will check in Outlook (for Outlook Addin), in a meeting request (MeetingItem / AppointmentItem), the recipients when they were added.
I am searching for an event / possibility in the MeetingItem / AppointmentItem it self...
So far I have not found any event, which add to the recipients is responsible.
Can someone give me as a tip on how I should proceed?

Thank you
Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way over the ItemSend event:

```
        readonly Outlook.Application _outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        _outlookApp.ItemSend += new ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(OutlookAppItemSend);
    }

    void OutlookAppItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel)
    {
        if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            var appt = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
            foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in appt.Recipients)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Rctp {0} ", recipient.Name));
            }

        }....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how do I know if the recipients have been changed, that event fires on any change in the appointmentItem, but i am able to filter with the name.

```
readonly Outlook.Application _outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _outlookApp.ItemLoad += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemLoadEventHandler(test_ItemLoad);
}

void test_ItemLoad(object item)
{
    if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
    {
        var appt = item as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
        appt.PropertyChange += new ItemEvents_10_PropertyChangeEventHandler(appt_PropertyChange);
    }
}

void appt_PropertyChange(string name)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Name: {0}", name));
    xxx
}
```

xxx: Here I'd just like to go through now the recipients of the item, if it has changed. Unfortunately, I do not know how to get back to my Appointment Item ....